# How to create nested list from flatten list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a function to create a nested list.

For example:

```
input= ['a','b','c','','d','e','f','g','','d','s','d','a','']
```

I want to create a sublist before `''`

As a return I want a nested list like:

```
[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f','g'],['d','s','d','a']]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following implementation

```
>>> def foo(inlist, delim = ''):
    start = 0
    try:
        while True:
            stop = inlist.index(delim, start)
            yield inlist[start:stop]
            start = stop + 1
    except ValueError:
            # if '' may not be the end delimiter 
            if start < len(inlist):
                yield inlist[start:]
        return


>>> list(foo(inlist))
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['d', 's', 'd', 'a']]
```

Another possible implementation could be by [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). But then you have to filter the result to remove the ['']. But though it might look to be one-liner yet the above implementation is more pythonic as its intuitive and readable

```
>>> from itertools import ifilter, groupby
>>> list(ifilter(lambda e: '' not in e,
             (list(v) for k,v in groupby(inlist, key = lambda e:e == ''))))
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['d', 's', 'd', 'a']]
```

Comment: This only returns the correct list if the input ends with `''`. eg `['a', '', 'b']` returns `[['a']]` instead of `[['a'], ['b']]`

Comment: @Tim: As per the problem statement `I want to create a sublist before ''`

Answer (score 4):

I'd use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
l = ['a','b','c','','d','e','f','g','','d','s','d','a','']
from itertools import groupby
[list(g) for k, g in groupby(l, bool) if k]
```

gives

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['d', 's', 'd', 'a']]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def nester(nput):
   out = [[]]
      for n in nput:
         if n == '':
            out.append([])
         else:
            out[-1].append(n)
    if out[-1] == []:
       out = out[:-1]
    return out
```

edited to add check for empty list at end

Comment: but it return [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['d', 's', 'd', 'a'], []] in the shell, how to eliminate the [] at the end?

Comment: Add an `if not out[-1]: out.pop()` before the `return`